# Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "ERROR [57014]

Tags: postgresql, powershell

Need help with my Powershell. I am getting error

`Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "ERROR [57014] ERROR: canceling statement due to statement timeout; Error while executing the query" At line:1 char:1`

My PowerShell as below:

```
$datetime = (Get-Date).ToString(); 
$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew() 
$DBConnectionString ="Dsn=PostgreSQL;database=test;server=10.x.x.xx;port=5432;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx" 
$DBConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection; $DBConn.ConnectionString = $DBConnectionString; 
$DBConn.Open(); 
$DBCmd = $DBConn.CreateCommand(); 
$DBCmd.CommandText= get-content "C:\data1.sql" 
$rdr=$DBCmd.ExecuteReader(); 
$instance = "DB\DBTEST" 
$userId = "sa" 
$password = "xxxx" 
$sqlconn = "Data Source=$instance;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Conversion; User Id=$userId; Password=$password"; 
$sqlbc = new-object system.data.sqlclient.Sqlbulkcopy($sqlconn); 
$sqlbc.BulkCopyTimeout = 0; 
$sqlbc.DestinationTableName="Table"; 
$sqlbc.WriteToServer($rdr); 
$sw.Stop(); 
Write-Host "[$($datetime)] [data1] Elapsed time $($sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds) miliseconds"
```

Really appreciate your help

Comment: *Dsn=PostgreSQL* I removed the incorrect SQL Server tag.

Comment: As per the error you received, how long is this running for before it errors? Have you looked into the ```CommandTimeout``` property of the connection?

Answer (score 1):

Database timeouts means database network accessibility (e.q. firewalls) or DB down issues most of the time. First of all try to check TCP connectivity to DB:

```
New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient('10.x.x.xx', 5432)
```

If it throws errors you or your admins have to open access to DB port to your workstation first.

Comment: I have ping and telnet, its successful. but still getting that error

Comment: Can you access DB from other Postgres clients like pgAdmin from your workstation?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was getting this timeout error because my client was sending too much data and the execution would timeout.